# How to restart an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have code that alerts the current month plus the last two months:

```
 var cMonth = new Date().getMonth();
 var currentMonth, pastMonth2, pastMonth3 = 0

 var months = [
    "January", 
    "February", 
    "March", 
    "April", 
    "May", 
    "June",
    "July", 
    "August", 
    "September", 
    "October", 
    "November",
    "December"
  ]
    currentMonth = months[cMonth];
    pastMonth2 = months[cMonth - 1];
    pastMonth3 = months[cMonth - 2];

  alert(pastMonth3 + " " + pastMonth2 + " " + currentMonth);
```

However if the month is Jan or Feb I want it to "restart the array" and print Dec and Nov, basically printing the last elements of the array. The only fix I could think of is adding validation with if statements but they don't work properly, not to mention I feel like is not an adequate solution (what if Instead of months is days of the month and I wanto to print the last 12 days?)

```
  if(cMonth == 1){ //prints Undefined Jan, Feb
    currentMonth = months[1]
    pastMonth2 = months[0]
    pastMonth3 = months[11]
  }
  if (cMonth == 0) { //prints Nov, Dec and Jan!
    currentMonth = months[0]
    pastMonth2 = months[11]
    pastMonth3 = months[10]
  } else {
    currentMonth = months[cMonth];
    pastMonth2 = months[cMonth - 1];
    pastMonth3 = months[cMonth - 2];
  }

  alert(pastMonth3 + " " + pastMonth2 + " " + currentMonth);
```

Comment: Seems like you are simply looking for `(cMonth + 0) % 12`, `(cMonth + 11) % 12`, and `(cMonth + 10) % 12` for the indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) can be used to get month names :

```js
const monthName = m => new Date(0, m).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' })

var month = new Date().getMonth();

console.log( monthName(month    ) ) // currentMonth 
console.log( monthName(month - 1) ) // pastMonth2
console.log( monthName(month - 2) ) // pastMonth3

console.log( monthName(-2) ) // November
console.log( monthName(13) ) // February
```

Answer (score 2):

modulo operator (**%**) is done for this
(==Remainder  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_() )

```
const getMonthNumber = nMonth => (nMonth %12 +12) %12
```

There is 12 month, so this is a system on base == 12 (or == months.length)
 the first `+12` is for negative numbers
 the second `%12` is for positive numbers

this (arrow function) is like :

```
function getMonthNumber(nMonth)
{
  let n = nMonth %12 
  n = n +12       // if n is negative
  return n %12    // if n is positive, so (n %12 +12) > 12 and we need to use a modulo again
}
```

sample code =>

```js
var months = [ 'January',   'February', 'March',    'April'
             , 'May',       'June',     'July',     'August'
             , 'September', 'October',  'November', 'December'
             ]


const getMonthNumber = nMonth => (nMonth %12 +12) %12

var cMonth       = 0                 // January
  , currentMonth = months[ cMonth ]
  , pastMonth2   = months[ getMonthNumber( cMonth -1 )]
  , pastMonth3   = months[ getMonthNumber( cMonth -2 )] 


console.log(currentMonth , pastMonth2 , pastMonth3 )


console.log('month 17...', months[ getMonthNumber(   17 ) ])
console.log('month -6...', months[ getMonthNumber(   -6 ) ])
console.log('month 187..', months[ getMonthNumber(  187 ) ])
console.log('month -300.', months[ getMonthNumber( -300 ) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the pattern:

```
cMonth      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
pastMonth3 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9 10
```

Then cMonth(12) = 12 - 2 = 10.

And cMonth(1) =    1 - (-10) = 11

So one function might be

```
  function pastMonth3(cMonth) {
    return cMonth - (9+cMonth); 
  }
```

This simply returns an index into your "months" array.  You can use it like this:

```
 var month = months[pastMonth3(cMonth)];
```

Comment: How does a negative number works in the array since the function would be -9 for 1? 
 `1 - (  9 + 1 )` or am I not getting this?

Answer (score 1):

Or, add 12 to any index that is less than zero to rotate it to the right month:

```js
var currentMonth, pastMonth2, pastMonth3 = 0
    
     var months = [
        "January", 
        "February", 
        "March", 
        "April", 
        "May", 
        "June",
        "July", 
        "August", 
        "September", 
        "October", 
        "November",
        "December"
      ]
        i = months.indexOf("January")
        currentMonth = months[i]
        i = i-1;   
        pastMonth2 = months[i<0?i+12:i];
        i = i-1;
        pastMonth3 = months[i<0?i+12:i];
    
      console.log(pastMonth3, pastMonth2, currentMonth)
```

Comment: lol, ternary indexes :p (btw, nothing wrong about it per se, I just needed a split second more to parse the code)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.slice` supports such an behaviour:

```js
var months = [
    "January", 
    "February", 
    "March", 
    "April", 
    "May", 
    "June",
    "July", 
    "August", 
    "September", 
    "October", 
    "November",
    "December"
  ]
  
  var cMonth = 0; // january
  
  var currentMonth = months.slice(cMonth, cMonth + 1)[0];
  var pastMonth2 = months.slice(cMonth - 1)[0];
  var pastMonth3 = months.slice(cMonth - 2)[0];
  
  console.log(currentMonth, pastMonth2, pastMonth3)
```

This will log `January December November`

Comment: For those wondering like I was  when you supply slice with a negative number it subtracts the number from the string's length.